# Rearrangement of 1,1-Dichloro-1a,9b-dihydro-1H-cyclopropa[l]phenanthrene on heating

Tags: organic-chemistry, rearrangements

[image]

Due to angle strain , the three membered ring is not stable. So i think it would break and kick out one of the chlorine atoms resulting in the formation of a carbene. But i don't know how to proceed further and how it finally breaks into 2 products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is a simple homolytic bond fission to give a carbene and a stable aromatic compound (Phenanthrene). Here's the mechanism:
[image]